# CSS not loading properly after adding the ModelError MVC Web api 5

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

We are using bundling, and CSS not loading properly after adding the ModelError MVC Web api 5
Here is our code in web api controller:

```
                    string errorMessage = (string)TempData["errorMsg"];
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(errorMessage))
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("AccountNumber", errorMessage);
                }
```

Actually when we are posting our data in the post action method we are redirecting from post to get action method if we got any error in the request.

Here is my html:

```
<div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse show" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
    <div class="card-block">

        <div class="bank_account">
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-12 col-md-4 col-12">
                    <label>Account Holder Name</label>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-12 col-md-8 col-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.BankAccount.AccountHolderName, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Account Holder Name" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BankAccount.AccountHolderName, "", new { @class = "text-danger holder_name" })
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="row">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BankAccount)
            </div>

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-12 col-md-4 col-12">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-12 col-md-8 col-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.AgreeWithTermCondtion, new { @class = "term_height" }) I agree with <a class="tmc" id="anch_terms_and_conditions" href="javascript:void(0)">Terms &amp; Conditions </a>
                        </label>
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AgreeWithTermCondtion, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="row mt-2">

                <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-12 col-md-4 col-12">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-12 col-md-8 col-12">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn_pay" id="btn_create_dd_plan"> Create Plan </button>

                    @CancellationButtion()
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your html with below one :

```
<div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse show" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
    <div class="card-block">
 @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="bank_account">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-12 col-md-4 col-12">
                    <label>Account Holder Name</label>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-12 col-md-8 col-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.BankAccount.AccountHolderName, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Account Holder Name" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BankAccount.AccountHolderName, "", new { @class = "text-danger holder_name" })
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="row">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BankAccount)
            </div>

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-12 col-md-4 col-12">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-12 col-md-8 col-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.AgreeWithTermCondtion, new { @class = "term_height" }) I agree with <a class="tmc" id="anch_terms_and_conditions" href="javascript:void(0)">Terms &amp; Conditions </a>
                        </label>
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AgreeWithTermCondtion, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="row mt-2">

                <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-12 col-md-4 col-12">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-12 col-md-8 col-12">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn_pay" id="btn_create_dd_plan"> Create Plan </button>

                    @CancellationButtion()
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```